# Failure to include pdf files in a Windows 11 computer using LuaLaTex MikTex, but ok in Windows 10

Tags: errors, luatex, pdf, includegraphics

I am a reasonably apt LaTeX user, being a local reference to solve problems. However, this baffles me and I could use some help. I already did a lot of checking on both installations, and reinstalled `MikTeX` in Windows 11.

I have a file that works in a Windows 10 computer but does not work in a Windows 11 computer... This is a minimal version of it (it is a big file, with many figures, but this MWE does not work either).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{C:/GitHub/TopicosBuscaMineracaoTexto/Imagens/SemanticaLatente2}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:semanticalatente2}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! error: (file C:/GitHub/TopicosBuscaMineracaoTexto/Imagens/SemanticaLatente2.pdf)
(pdf inclusion): reading image failed
! ==> Fatal error ocurred, no output PDF produced!
```

I am using `LuaHTeX`, Version 1.15.0 (MikTeX 22.3), `MikTeX`. Both are configured to automatically download packages. Also, it seems that they can include graphics created with `inkscape` (automatically by ´LuaLaTeX`and includesvg) but not exported by`yed` (only in Windows 11).

**Update:**

I used Inkscape to open and save the PDFs files that were not being read and LuaLaTeX manage to compile the document. Both PDF 1.4 and 1.5 worked fine.

I couldn´t find the cause yet. Why it was working in one system but not in the other? Maybe some other installation interfere with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Does it work if you copy the image to the current folder and remove the absolute path?

Comment: if the graphic is stored in a git repo: Check if you locally really have the file and not only e.g. a lfs pointer (look at the size of the pdf, if it is only 1kb it is probably not a real pdf).

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, but both alternatives were tested and were not the causa. Please see my work around.